# How to Implement a Table with scale within?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, checkbox, tabular

I would like to have a Form with a table in it.
The first row will describe a Scale.
In each cell in the table, there will be a a checkBox button, that will have my choice. (only one can be chosen (validation))

```
              **1**             **2**           **3**
a)______________checkBoxbttn_____________________   checkBoxbttn____________________              V

b)     ____________  checkBoxbttn___________________________        V        ___________________      checkBoxbttn
```

After marking only one checkBox in every row (validation), I'll need to save each row's choose in a parameter, for future use.
For the example above: int a = 3; int b = 2;

How can I implement that?
How the validations looks like?

Comment: Your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `TableLayoutPanel` with one column and any number of rows. In each cell, place a `Panel`. In each panel, place three `RadioButton` controls, to ensure that only one among those is selected.

To know which RadioButton is selected, you can iterate through each Panel's controls and returning the first one checked.

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var row in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            var panel = row as Panel;
            if (panel == null) continue;
            var checkedButton = 
                panel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
            if (checkedButton == null) continue;
            //Process your radiobutton here.
        }
    }
```

To assign a specific value to a RadioButton, I would create a class deriving from it, with a property representing your value.

Example:

```
class ScaleRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public int MyScale { get; set; }
}
```